# getting status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url ... in asp.net using core webApi?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, angular-services

Getting 404 error in ASP.NET Core Web API. With ASP.NET I am using Angular 7 for front end. When I click on save button of a form, the form data reaches to post method in angular but after click on save it shows 404 error. For this form I created first model where I define its property for database then I created controller for that model and use that property that I declared in model.

Angular service ts file:

```js
export class MurderService {
   BaseUrl :string ='';
  constructor( private http:HttpClient, private config:ConfigService) {
    this.BaseUrl=config.getApiURI();
   }

  murderQuestionnaire(data: any){
     var murderBody={
       Dead: data.Dead,
       Wounded: data.Wounded,
       CriminalsInvolved: data.CriminalsInvolved,
       CriminalAppearance: data.CriminalAppearance,
       VehiclesUsed: data.VehiclesUsed,
       WeaponsDescription :data.WeaponsDescription
     };
     return this.http.post(this.BaseUrl +'/Complians' , murderBody);//upto here data reaches 
      successfully
  }
}
```

API controller for  this service:

```cs
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ComplainMurderController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Complians")]
        //api:/Complians
        public void PostComplainMurder(Complians complian)
        {
            var complianMurder = new Complians()
            {
                Dead = complian.Dead,
                Wounded = complian.Wounded,
                CriminalsInvolved = complian.CriminalsInvolved,
                CriminalAppearence = complian.CriminalAppearence,
                VehiclesUsed = complian.VehiclesUsed,
                WeaponsDescription = complian.WeaponsDescription
            };
            try
            {
               // var result = await complian.Add(complianMurder);
                AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext();
                authenticationContext.Add(complianMurder);
                authenticationContext.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error

> POST http://localhost:49601/api/Complians 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Probably because your route is defined as `Complians` but you are calling `api/Complians`.

Comment: @lan Kemp upto api its the asp.net url and /complians its table in database.

Comment: Mixing "Complian" and "Complain" everywhere is bound to lead to mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller route is defined as `api/[controller]` (in your case this leads to `api/ComplainMurder`). Your action is defined as `Complians`. These combined is your actual route: `api/ComplainMurder/Complians`, which does not match `api/Complians`.

Changing your Angular 7 side with this will fix it:

```
return this.http.post(this.BaseUrl +'/ComplainMurder/Complians' , murderBody);
```

Side note: be careful with incorrect/inconsistent spelling (complian instead of complain) as it's bound to lead to confusion and/or mistakes in the future.

Comment: you means that i need to change api/[controller] to api/[ComplianMurder].?

Comment: Your action route is different from your Angular post URL. You have to change either side so they match.

`return this.http.post(this.BaseUrl +'/ComplainMurder/Complians' , murderBody);`

Comment: @WasifZaman There is a button to press to accept an answer. It should be to the left of my answer and look like a check mark (✓)